# How to load product image gallery of the selected products inside div using jquery?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I have custom module which consist of product listing with radio buttons.I want to display the image gallery of the selected products inside particular div using jquery.

Comment: You need to make an Ajax request, create blocks with response and pass it back. In jQuery  you'll check if the response is with right status and if it's contains your updated blocks (products). If yes then replace html in specific element. If you have more specific problem then edit your question and add code that you're having problems with.

Comment: @versedi thanks for your reply can you  give me  example code of block response .which consists of product image gallery .